# How to compare a userform variable to a dimensioned variable?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a problem in which a userform textbox Thickness formatted #.### (0.250)example.  I have declared 2 variables as variant tMax and tMin and assigned tMax = Cdec("0.280") and tMin = Cdec("0.240").

The following code give me and error.

```
If Cells(nextRow, l).Value > tMax Or Cells(nextRow, l).Value < tMin Then
    Cells(nextRow, l).Font.Color = vbRed
        Else: Cells(nextRow, l).Font.Color = vbBlack
End If
```

What I am trying to do is if the value entered into the userform is >.280 or < .240 then change the font to red.

Greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error given is:

Comment: Application-defined or object-defined error 1004

Comment: What's the value of `nextRow`?

Comment: nextRow is 7002.  the next available empty row.

Comment: Can you share your code that determines `nextRow`? Is the sheet protected?

Comment: And what is the value of `l`?

Comment: ...guessing `l` is meant to be `1` (or is actually a variable but has value = 0)

Comment: In the posted code we have an `l` and if `l` is not initialized the value is `0` and the code will run into RTE 1004.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  the "l" (lower case L) is for the column... cells(nextrow, l).value.  It is an entry from the userform .

Comment: When using the locals window, the value does show up.  I am guessing it is a formating issue,

Comment: Duhhh..... I am so stupid.  Syntax, Syntax, Syntax.  Cells uses numbers, not letters and I didnt catch the post by Tim Williams.  Changed the "l" to a 12 (column number) and all works perfectly.  Thank you all for your input.